# Get list of values at specific position in TinyDB

Tags: python, json, tinydb

I have a TinyDB for Python and the data with multiple lines in the structure
`{'service': {'key1': '', 'key2': '', 'key3': '', 'key4': '', 'key5': ''}}`

I wanted to get only "service" from all the lines of the database assuming the "service" real name is not known.

How to achieve with tinyDB Query()?

`db.all()[0]` just give entire line in index 0.

I am expecting to get only "service".

Comment: what is the `print(type(db.all()[0]))`?

Comment: Its `<class 'tinydb.table.Document'>`

Comment: Posted an answer, the other way, which is more straightforward to get `service`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit tricky:

```
>>> list(db.all()[0].keys())[0]
service

>>> list(db.all()[0].values())
[{'key1': '', 'key2': '', 'key3': '', 'key4': '', 'key5': ''}]
```

Answer (score 0):

To get `service` from all the outputs,

```
def get_key_info(db_output, key):
   return [row[key] for row in db_output]

output = db.all()
get_key_info(output, 'service')
```

To just get the `service` first row,

```
db.get(doc_id=1)['service']
```